# Cannot import release from networkx

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, networkx

I'm trying to import release from networkx but I got the error below on ipython notebook. 
I have networkx installed successfully.
Could anyone help?

Code:

```
import networkx as nx
from networkx import release
print "NetworkX version:     %6.6s (need at least 1.7)" % nx.__version__
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-675a5f60bf8e> in <module>()
     28 
     29 # Networkx is a library for working with networks
---> 30 import networkx as nx
     31 from networkx import release
     32 print "NetworkX version:     %6.6s (need at least 1.7)" % nx.__version__

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/networkx/__init__.py in <module>()
     41 
     42 # Release data
---> 43 from networkx import release
     44 
     45 __author__   = '%s <%s>\n%s <%s>\n%s <%s>' % \

ImportError: cannot import name release
```

Comment: What version of `NetworkX` are you using? I cannot reproduce with 1.9.1.

Comment: Does updating NetworkX help, or is this the latest release?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error when importing networkx 1.9.1. Simply reinstalling fixed the issue.

`pip uninstall networkx && pip install networkx`

Comment: it is not working for me! I have python 3.9 and installed 2.5.1; and get the same error!

Answer (score 0):

Just open cmd and run this command

```html
python -m pip install networkx --upgrade pip
```